# Getting the correct Google client ID for Chrome users with multiple accounts

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-contacts-api

I'm trying to get the Google Client Id (found under https://plus.google.com/me) of a user corresponding to the account he's currently connected with.

Explanation: when connecting with your gmail account on Chrome, the result of the code given here (https://developers.google.com/+/web/people/) gives the user's client ID that I need to use the Google Payment API.
The problem is if the user has multiple accounts connected on Chrome.

Example: Our user has an email account for work (WEmail) and a personal email account (PEmail). He first connects to chrome using his WEmail. Then adds his PEmail to the list of Chrome connected accounts. Then our user wishes to make a payment on an extension he has installed, with his PEmail.

The issue here is that to process such a payment you need the google client ID of that user, and when you fetch it, you will get the one of the first connected account (WEmail) and not the one of the current used account (PEmail). Which makes it impossible to process the payment since you might not be serving the right account.

Is there any way to get all the currently used ids of a user or jsut the currently used id?
If not, are there plans to integrate such a solution in the short term?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can ask for a feature request regarding this on this [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new) and [the chromium tracker](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list).

Comment: I created an issue here https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/110507707#comment1 as well :)